# Powershell: icACLs chokes on paths with spaces

Tags: powershell, robocopy, icacls

I'm looping through a directory structure and saving the permissions from each directory inside itself using icACLs.exe.  I need to use robocopy to find all the paths since the a lot of the full paths exceed 260 characters.  Some also include spaces.

I seem to have this working well enough until it comes to the spaces, then I get-

icacls.exe : Y:/this/path/has/ spaces /in/it" /save Perms.txt: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
robocopy Y:\Public NULL /l /e /nfl /xx /nc /ns /njh | Out-File Y:\results.txt
$results = Get-Content Y:\results.txt
ForEach ($sfile in $results) {
    $sfile = $sfile.Trim()
    cd $sfile
    New-Item -Name Perms.txt -ItemType File -force
    icacls.exe "$sfile" /save Perms.txt    
}
```

I've tried containing $sfile in quotes, braces, but I can't seem to get it to run smoothly through them. I've also noticed that all paths with spaces seem to end with a double quote in the error, though I am not sure why. Thoughts?

Comment: `icacls.exe "'$sfile'" /save Perms.txt`? Also consider looking into Get-ACL and Set-ACL cmdlets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [icacls permissions script in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365551/icacls-permissions-script-in-powershell)